# How to generate random line graphs up to 10 iterations?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have done coding for one graph, how to randomly generate 10 graphs with the same code. I want a unique graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# line 1 points
x1 = [1,2,3]
y1 = [2,4,1]
# plotting the line 1 points 
plt.plot(x1, y1, label = "line 1")
# naming the x axis
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
# naming the y axis
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
# giving a title to my graph
plt.title('Two lines on same graph!')
# show a legend on the plot
plt.legend()`enter code here`
# function to show the plot
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should clarify "randomly generate" part.

Comment: Also, what you mean by "unique graph".

Comment: I need one code to generate 10 graphs with different values.

Comment: @lapizcontent remember to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your question.

Answer (score 5):

If I am not mistaken, you just want 10 graphs with random lines on them.

From your example I assume you want only integer values.

Using [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) it is possible to generate lists of random values. In the following example the arrays will have length 10 and will have values ranging from 0 to 15.

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(low=0, high=15, size=10)
y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=15, size=10)
```

I have not understood if you also require this arrays to be distinct.

Let's proceed to draw 10 random graphs:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def draw_plot(sub):
    """Draw a random graph."""
    # line 1 points
    x = np.sort(np.random.randint(low=0, high=15, size=10))
    y = np.random.randint(low=0, high=15, size=10)
    # plotting the line 1 points 
    sub.plot(x, y, label = "line 1")
    # naming the x axis
    sub.set_xlabel('x - axis')
    # naming the y axis
    sub.set_ylabel('y - axis')
    # giving a title to my graph
    sub.set_title('Two lines on same graph!')
    # show a legend on the plot
    sub.legend()


plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))

for i in range(10):
    sub = plt.subplot(2, 5, i+1)
    draw_plot(sub)
plt.show()
```

The result is the following: [image: 10 random graphs]

Comment: bonus challenge: Generate random but REALISTIC data which doesn't keep hopping all over the place, rather goes up and down consistently, but at random still

Comment: Just use something like a [savgol filter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) to make it look arbitrarily smooth.